# Fetching immediate lower and higher value of a given number from a List<Integer>

Tags: java, algorithm, math, java-8, java-stream

```
List<Integer> list =  Arrays.asList(1, 2, 4, 5,7, 8, 9);
int n = 3;
```

When user input integer as 3 then program should result as 2 and 4 in an above given list.

Comment: Consider your input to be `Arrays.asList(1, 2, 9, 5,7, 8, 9, 4)`, what would be your outputs corresponding to for `n=3` and `n=9`?

Comment: Actually this list representing a drop down as priorities, Once a priority created we are not allowing that priority again in the drop down itself which means we restricted the  duplicates,

Comment: If user select minimum or maximum priority then system should result same.
if Arrays.asList(1, 2, 9, 5,7, 8, 9, 4)
if n= 3 then result is 2,4
if n= 9 then result is 9
if n= 1 then result is 1

Comment: Then you are possibly seeking a sorting of the values as well during the process.

Comment: Yes sorting requires @Naman, If you observe my given list  is already sorted and no duplicates also, Thanq :-) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Collectors.partitioningBy`:

```
Map<Boolean, List<Integer>> m = list.stream()
    .filter(i -> i != n)
    .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(i -> i > n));

Integer lower = m.get(false).get(m.get(false).size() - 1);
Integer higher = m.get(true).get(0);
```

Additional check whether both `m.get(false)` and `m.get(true)` are not empty might be needed.

Comment: thank you very much. Its working.